# Component for increase and decrease in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a component for increase and decrease for flutter like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just use this lib:

[number_inc_dec](https://pub.dev/packages/number_inc_dec)

Default style:

```
NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(
  controller: TextEditingController(),
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
),
```

Using with your custom style:

```
NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(
    controller: TextEditingController(),
    buttonArrangement: ButtonArrangement.incRightDecLeft,
    decIcon: Icons.remove_circle,
    incIcon: Icons.add_circle,
    autovalidate: true,
    isInt: true,
    initialValue: 1,
    incIconSize: 50,
    decIconSize: 50,
    incIconDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border(
                               top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                               bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                           ),
                       ),
    decIconDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border(
                               top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                               bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                           ),
                       ),
    widgetContainerDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  width: 0,
                                ),
                              ),
    onIncrement: (count) {
        print(count);
    },
    onDecrement: (count) {
        print(count);
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 10
)
```